# Best tutorials for understanding settings/preferences for os x apps

Tags: objective-c, macos, settings, preferences

I am trying to write a simple app (a menulet) and want to have a settings page for it. Is there ant good resource that can be recommended for getting started with the basics of adding settings to an app. I have spent days looking on google for decent results, but I can't find anything that tells me what I want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [apple tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Concepts/Application.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000702-CJBJFACH) on the subject. Although it's rather verbose, it's nonetheless useful.

[This particular chapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Tasks/OtherApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000711-BBCBAGAH) is dedicated to including Preference Panes framework into a standalone application.